# jq find a key name in multi-map structured JSON

Tags: json, jq

I have this JSON object that maps the compatibility of patch sets to specific software versions.

```json
{
   "compatibility":{
      "v7.11.x":[
         "7.12.1",
         "7.12.0",
         "7.11.2",
         "7.11.1",
         "7.11.0"
      ],
      "v7.13.x":[
         "7.14.2",
         "7.14.1",
         "7.14.0",
         "7.13.1",
         "7.13.0"
      ],
      "v7.15.x":[
         "8.1.0",
         "8.0.1",
         "8.0.0",
         "7.17.1",
         "7.17.0",
         "7.16.1",
         "7.16.0",
         "7.15.1",
         "7.15.0"
      ]
   }
}
```

Would it be possible for `jq` to return the patch set name (e.g. "v7.15.x") when given
the specific version (e.g. "8.1.0")?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it's pretty straightforward actually.

```
.compatibility | to_entries[] | select(.value | index("8.1.0")) .key
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/dqwW6fvSLC3)</sup>

In case it's unclear, the version string doesn't have to be hardcoded; it may come from outside the program too:

```bash
jq --arg version 8.1.0 '.compatibility | to_entries[] | select(.value | index($version)) .key'
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need to query the same data set several times, it might be worth creating an index object, store it in a variable, and perform the lookup from there:

```bash
(.compatibility | with_entries({value: .key, key: .value[]})) as $lookup

# various ways to lookup multiple versions
| $lookup["8.0.1", "7.11.2"], $lookup["7.16.1"]
```

```json
"v7.15.x"
"v7.11.x"
"v7.15.x"
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/TE7RiAmbdo6)